# MongoDB query based on date plus time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i've to run a query like this (sql) in MongoDb 4:

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) < NOW()
```

Basically, I want to find all the documents, in the PENDING state, whose creation date PLUS TWO HOURS is less than now .. Let me explain: I want to find all the documents in the PENDING state that have been in PENDING for more than two hours.
I feel stupid, but I am failing to do this with MongoDb.
I also created a playground:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/4bifqiX2KMJ

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can add hours in ISO date using [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#perform-addition-on-a-date), convert string date to ISO date using [dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/index.html),

```
let date = new Date();

db.collection.find({
  status: "pending",
  $expr: {
    $lt: [
      {
        $add: [
          // convert string date to ISOdate, if its already then use only "$inserted_at"
          { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$inserted_at" } },
          // add milliseconds
          7200000 // (60*60*2000)
        ]
      },
      date
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ro46zcFtiE-)

---

Or subtract from current date and then compare the condition,

```
let date = new Date();
date = new Date(date.getHours()-2); //subtract 2 hours

db.collection.find({
  status: "pending",
  $expr: {
    $lt: [
      { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$inserted_at" } },
      date
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iQKtuR2VDCA)

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I am not understanding: the two hours must be added to the date of the document itself, not to the current date or to a preset date. I have to find, as written, all the documents in "Pending" status where the insert_at plus two hours is in the past ..

Comment: Have you check and experiment with first example? that is similar to your select query. *I have to find, as written* but your mysql select query will find written?